# How to use child attribute as text content using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to use the attribute (data-text) of a child element to display within the parent as text content. As there are many of these buttons it needs to only take the attribute of the child. Please can you advise?

```js
var textAt = $(this).children('svg').attr("data-text");
$('.button').text(textAt);
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #8d49f9;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="button">
  <svg class="liquid-button" data-text="See Projects">
  </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop each of your `button` using `class`.
2. Find `svg` inside them.
3. Your are using data attribute so use `data` to find value.

Example:

```js
$(".button").each(function(index) {
  var textAt = $(this).find('svg').data("text");
  $(this).text(textAt);
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #8d49f9;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="button">
  <svg class="liquid-button" data-text="See Projects">
  </svg>
</a>
<a class="button">
  <svg class="liquid-button" data-text="See Projects12">
  </svg>
</a>
```